# How to turn on an iPhone with a broken power button?

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone 4. It has been off for 2 years. I don't know which iOS is on it and my power button is broken.

How can I turn it on without it ? It just shows the battery logo not the apple one.

Comment: If you charge it, it should turn on by itself (I think). Just wait an hour.

Answer (score 2):

Plug in your phone to charge it.

It will turn on.

Go to Settings -> General -> Shutdown to turn it off.